# Question regarding contact to institutional professors

Tags: publications

**Background:**

I am a second year undergraduate in Computer science and Artificial Intelligence from India. I also have developed a keen interest in research in mathematics after reading a lot of research papers since high school. I have written three papers in number theory,  two coauthored with a friend who is a freshman and one solo paper. Two of the papers have been accepted by high level journals and one has been submitted for publication.

**Question:**

I have written all these papers during my first year at my institute, however, I have done all of my work without any mentorship or consultancy. For my solo paper, I felt that paper had a major result so I mailed some of professors in my references to know if my works are good enough and I got a positive response. Now, I want to know if I should let the number theory professor of my college know about my work as I don't know her personally but have mentioned my institute as my affiliation?

**P.S.** I am sorry if this post breaks the standards of this forum in any way and would delete it if suggested .

Comment: What concerns do you have that make you hesitate?

Comment: @Buffy Mainly the fact if the professor gets angry that I didn't contact anyone from my institute before submitting my work under their affiliation.

Comment: I doubt that will happen. Your affiliation is independent of any one professor. Take the advice of user Jeroen, though a face-to-face meet is usually superior for such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, contact the professor.
Especially because you don't know her personally. Just to get to know each other, since you are both interested in the same field and she might take an interest in your future progress. Furthermore, she can provide supervision/mentorship if/when you do need it in the future. It never hurts to have this connection.

Just sending an email introducing yourself and your work should be fine. It is then up to the professor what she does with it.